# multiple regex matches in pig for log files

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have 2 input files.

Input 1 (contains multiple URLs):

```
(http://a.com/search?q=cache:QD7vZRHkPQoJ:ca.xyz.com/jobs2/view/17069404+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca) (http://a.com/search?q=cache:G9323j2oNbAJ:ca.xyz.com/jobs2/view/5977065+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca) (http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11qAJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928+&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clnk&gl=hk) (http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11AJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928+&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clnk&gl=hk) (http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11qAJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928+&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=cl k&gl=hk)
```

Input 2 (contains the following regular expressions):

```
.*/view/(\\d+)([+|&|cd|)?]+)?
\/\/[^\x2f]+\.[a-z]{2}\/\d\/$
\/\/[^\?]+\.php\?[a-z]+=\d{3}_\d+$
\/\/[^\x3f]+\.php\?([a-z]+=[0-9]{2,3}&){5}[a-z]+=[0-9]{2,3}$)
```

My requirement is to match each of these regex to to see if they match any of the URLs in the first input file (many to many).

Do I have to write each regex separately using `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` or is there any better way to do it? (Can it be done by loading both files and using foreach/generate with field name for regex instead of actual expression like below?)

```
A = LOAD 'input1.txt' as line1;
B = LOAD 'input2.txt' as line2;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line1,'B.line2');
dump C;
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but those regex's look to be problematic.This `/[^\x3f]+\.php\?([a-z]+=[0-9]{2,3}&){5}[a-z]+=[0-9]{2,3}$)` expression contains an unbalanced parenthesis at the end. This `.*/view/(\\d+)([+|&|cd|)?]+)?` has `\\d+` a literal escape meaning match escape plus many `d`s. This `[+|&|cd|)?]+` is a character class with many alternation literals. You use `\d` in some places, `[0-9]` in others, you use hex `\x2f` and `\x3f` in character classes, when a literal would be fine, etc ...

Comment: I understand the isues with regex. Though the requirement is simply using a full file of multiple regex on a full file of logs.(URLs in this case). I will be getting the approved file with correct regex so that's not an issue. But I wanted to know how I can match each regex with each log record without a loop? Do I need a separate UDF in python or something?